# Newsletter Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am using a sendable data extension that I want to as a starting point for my newsletter journey in journey builder. The data extension gets data inserted from the DEManager that is configured on my website. Is it possible to use this data extension as a starting point for my journey and let it run every hour for new submissions? Right now I am using quite a work around, but that doesn’t work ideal.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't hesitate to share if you solved the issue.

Comment: Thanks @JeremyGarcia, this solved the issue. I couldn't select the right data extension, because there was a connected automation studio running. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understand right you want:

1. Someone submit a form
2. Contact details are inserted in a DE via Web Collect
3. Journey Builder to monitor this DE every hour
4. Inject people in a journey if they are new in the DE
5. Marketing activities in the journey

If this is correct, I am not sure why you have to do a work around. I would recommend you to simply use the Data Extension entry event. Select your DE (filters are optional). Then schedule a recurring automation like this:

[image]