# How to automate Journey for new subs - Data Extension Entry Source (Check once per day)

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions, automation

In journey builder, I'm trying to best understand the Data Extension "entry source" as a way to automate a Welcome Journey for new subscribers.  I've created a DE where new subscribers will manually be uploaded via a CSV (DE called "Client Welcome Queue"). I want Journey builder to check for new subscribers in that DE every morning at 6:00 AM. and add any new subscribers to the welcome Journey.

I see the Data Extension entry source, as well as setting a schedule for this to run. I don't see a way to separate new subscribers from old subscribers in terms of setting an attribute to check against. Does SFMC do this automatically?  Also the second step in this process is "Contact Filter", but I don't want to filter at all so can I just skip this? Screenshot here: https://www.screencast.com/t/ciEbgFzgk1

I've spent quite a bit of time reading up on this but nothing seems to answer my question although I fear it's blatantly obvious. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried adding a “time added” with a default value of now() to to a new de and run an query automation to add contacts to this at 5.45? You can then use this as an entry source and set the journey to run daily at 6 pm only admitting new contacts

Comment: Does the answer to a similar question helps you?

[Answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/218611/56057)

Comment: @JeremyGarcia Yes that is perfect. I was hoping there was an out-of-the-box approach.

Comment: @Data_Kid that is a pretty interesting workaround, It would techincally work but I think the out of the box solution is the winner. Thanks for taking the time to answer!